# Is "Denali" a next verion of SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

While tracking a site I came to know that Microsoft has launched a new server for SQL [LINK](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/future-editions.aspx)

My queries:

Is "Denali" is SQL SERVER 2011 ? I mean is it a stand alone server or just a feature addition to SQL Server 2008?

If "Denali" is new version of SQL Server. Than do I need to uninstall SQL Server 2005 [which is present in my system] before installing "Denali" ?

Comment: Everyone should use codenames. It's so cute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Microsoft SQL Server 2012 is codenamed "Denali". That means the internal name for the project is "Denali" and this is what MS employees refer to when talking about the new version of the SQL Server.

We don't know for sure whether the name will be SQL Server 2012, hence the code name.

A [community technology preview version (beta) is provided by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6a04f16f-f6be-4f92-9c92-f7e5677d91f9&displaylang=en) to see the new upcoming features.

As for your questions: Denali *might* be SQL Server 2011, but they also might change the naming to be SQL Server 20[somethingelse]. Denali **is** a standalone server and not an add-on. It **will be** the new SQL Server 2005/2008.

Second question, will you need to uninstall SQL Server 2005 - depends. If you want to use the new features of SQL Server "Denali" or SQL Server 2008 you would need to install these, but can keep using the SQL Server 2005 (not recommended, though).

Answer (score 2):

"Denali" is the next edition of SQL Server it is not a new feature of SQL Server 2008.

I wouldn't have thought you would need to un-install SQL 2005 as you can usually install different editions on the same machine.

Having said that, this is a beta version released as a Community Technology Preview.  I would recommend that you install this on to a test machine or if you have one a VM environment.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Barry, can you recommend me any Virtual Machine for Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

> Is "Denali" is SQL SERVER 2011

Maybe, maybe not. Maybe it is SQL Server 2012, or MS decides to change naming. It IS, though, asi t sas clearly on the side, the next generation of SQL Server.

> I mean is it a stand alone server or
>   just a feature addition to SQL Server
>   2008?

MS always has code names for in development technology, and if you read the side it is clear it is next generation SQL Server.

> Than do I need to uninstall SQL Server
>   2005 [which is present in my system]
>   before installing "Denali" ?

Given that since 2000 or 2005 SQL Server supports multiple installs in different instances side by side-  no, you do not need. tHat said, if you isntall Denali and your syste mbreaks you join the line of people realizing that MS is serious about "do not install beta technology on productive systems":

You are better off installing SQL 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a beta version, not final before several months.